# How to read multiple csv files with Reduce in R

Tags: r, reduce

I'm trying to extract one column from multiple .csv files using Reduce. 
What I have is

a vector with the path to every single .csv

```
filepaths
```

a function to read a .csv and return one of it's columns

```
getData <- function(path,column) {
   d = read.csv(path)
   d[,column]
}
```

and the Reduce function, to apply the getData function to every single filepath and store the results in a single collection (for demonstration I only take the first three path strings)

```
Reduce(function(path,acc) append(acc, getData(path,column)), filepaths[1:3],c())
```

If I do this, I get the following error, which occurs, when read.csv is called with one of the filepaths

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     'file' must be a character string or connection

This is strange, cause if I call the "getData" function manually like

```
getData(filepaths[1],col)
getData(filepaths[2],col)
getData(filepaths[3],col)
```

it works.

I know, I could do this with a for loop. But I want to understand, what the problem is.

Comment: try `do.call(rbind,lapply(filepaths, fread, select="colname"))`

Comment: you can do this too with your function `unlist(lapply(filepaths, function(x){ getData(x,1) }))` will read first column.

Comment: Why read the whole .csv and then extract only one column? inefficient. `fread` for example has a `select` argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. The problem is, that Reduce expects a function, that has the accumulator as FIRST parameter, and the element as second. I switched them. So the solution looks like this:

```
getData <- function(path,column) {
  d = read.csv(path)
  d[,column]
}

Reduce(function(acc,path) append(acc, getData(path,column)), filepaths[1:3],c())
```

Thanks for the hint with `fread`. I see that this is much better than `read.csv`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fread` from `data.table` to read in only the desired column, instead of reading in entire csv's and consequently dropping all columns but one, as in your function.

```
library(data.table)
unlist(lapply(filepaths, fread, select= "colname")) #output is a vector
```

Comment: Thanks this is a nice approach. But I'd also like to know how to do it with Reduce.

Comment: Not sure you can do this with `Reduce()`, or why you would want to, when there's simpler alternatives around.

Comment: I'm having some experiences with other function programming languages like Erlang and Scala, and I want to adopt the concepts, that I know from there. Reduce is one of these typical functional elements, that luckily are also available in R

Comment: That's exactly why what you're trying to do is very un-R like.

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce()` is used with functions that process data and return same kind of data. For example `reduceFun(x1,x2)` which compares x1 and x2 and returns the max will be called first with x1 and x2 being the 2 first elements of the vector, then the result will be passd as x1 and the be third element as x2:

```
reduceFun <- function(x1,x2) 
{
  print(paste("x1=",x1, " : x2=",x2, " : max=",max(x1,x2)));
  return(max(x1,x2))
}
> res <- Reduce(reduceFun, 1:10)
[1] "x1= 1  : x2= 2  : max= 2"
[1] "x1= 2  : x2= 3  : max= 3"
[1] "x1= 3  : x2= 4  : max= 4"
[1] "x1= 4  : x2= 5  : max= 5"
[1] "x1= 5  : x2= 6  : max= 6"
[1] "x1= 6  : x2= 7  : max= 7"
[1] "x1= 7  : x2= 8  : max= 8"
[1] "x1= 8  : x2= 9  : max= 9"
[1] "x1= 9  : x2= 10  : max= 10"
> res
[1] 10
```

So `Reduce()` is probably not what you want to use, there are many other ways as shown in other answers.

Comment: I see that, but actually, you can take an empty vector as the accumulator (as "init"), and pass this to your function in every iteration (as x1). One example would be, to add the result of read.csv to your accumulator with every iteration. And in the end, you have all the data in one collection. This is what I'm trying to do

Comment: this is why you can't use `Reduce()` like that for this operation

Comment: No, that's no problem, cause my function doesn't return a data.frame, but a vector by using append with the accumulator, and the result of getData

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
library(data.table)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path_here/CSV Files/")

WD="C:/Users/your_path_here/CSV Files/"
data<-data.table(read.csv(text="CashFlow,Cusip,Period"))

csv.list<- list.files(WD)
k=1

for (i in csv.list){
  temp.data<-read.csv(i)
  data<-data.table(rbind(data,temp.data))

  if (k %% 100 == 0)
    print(k/length(csv.list))

  k<-k+1
}
```